# Upgrading C# application from .net Framework 1.0 to 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, frameworks, upgrade

I'm trying to use the `VS2008` to upgrade an `1.0` app to `3.5`, but I have many many problems.

And I was wondering if any of you had this experience before, so it might be wonderful if he can share with us any tricks or (I don't know) so I can solve those problems after upgrading .NET applications.

Comment: I think you should be more specific. Do you need help with any problem you're having? If so, what are they?

Comment: Would you like to expand a little bit on problems you are having?

Comment: more than 1800 problem, it's an application with 45 tables

Comment: at least mention some recurring problems

Comment: Like deprecated functions, files not found, ...

Comment: What do you expect from us? We don't know what errors you have, what type of functionality you use.. Share some details of the error that occurs the most if you want us to help.

Comment: If you're not supposed to modify the code, what is the point of upgrading from 1.1 to 3.5?

Comment: Why, because the application is used by other application and it generate dll files who are not more supported by the other apps.

Comment: It's too complicated it use Java and C# (desktop and webservices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience the most routine thing is that after automatic conversion you have to manually set each project's target framework. That's the main difficulty if you have a big number of projects.

The other potential problem (though easily solved) is that you need to add references to new libraries in order to use new features.

And then you find out that you don't need ArrayLists and Arrays anymore. And so you start changing your code...